# не могу подключит Bootstrap в Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap

После создания проекта в Laravel 10 пытаюсь подключить Bootstrap следующим образом:

- composer require laravel/ui
- php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
- npm install(при выполнении данной команды 8 packages are looking for funding run `npm fund` for details)
- npm run dev запускает два сервера

> dev
> vite

LARAVEL v10.28.0  plugin v0.8.1

➜  APP_URL: http://localhost

VITE v4.5.0  ready in 7849 ms

➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
➜  Network: use --host to expose
➜  press h to show help

Однако стили, подключенные к blade файлам, не применяются!

Куда Laravel 10 и Bootstrap 5 свернули не туда?

Гуглил и смотрел видео,на предыдущих версиях все по другому!

Comment: Это не они свернули не туда (хотя и они тоже), а Вы куда-то не туда)) Просто берёте и ставите через npm i бутстрап. Руками. Потом импортируете файлы от бутстрапа в js файл входной, который подтягивает себе vite. Собираете всё -- готово.

Comment: i bootstrap установлен, как импортировать файлы и где эти файлы брать?

Answer (score 1):

У меня тоже возникла такая проблема, но вот по этой ссылке есть решение:
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-install-bootstrap-5-in-laravel-10example.html

Выполняешь следующие шаги:

1. Создаешь проект Laravel(composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app)
2. composer require laravel/ui --dev
3. php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
4. npm install bootstrap-icons --save-dev
5. открываем ручками файл по следующей директории в проекте Laravel (resources\sass\app.scss) заменяем все что там есть на:

   /* Fonts */
   @import url('https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=Nunito');
   /* Variables */
   @import 'variables';
   /* Bootstrap */
   @import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
   @import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';
6. npm install
7. npm run build
8. php artisan serve

Все команды, за исключением пункта 5 вводятся в терминале. Необходимо помнить, что в момент установки нужно находиться в директории проекта.

Ну и собственно описанное тут находиться по ссылке выше, на английском языке более подробно.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! 1.[Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). 2. переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык

Comment: дякую за пораду!

Comment: Спасибо,при много благодарен, все получилось :)))